# How to send csv file and xlsx file in chunks using flask?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, flask, stream

I have a pandas dataframe from a query in my database, based on API parameters I want to send a file from this dataframe. The file can be csv or xlsx format. Memory is a limited resource on this case and some edge cases I might have to send big files.

So far I have something like this:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
from flask import request, send_file, make_response


@app.route('/download_file', methods=['POST'])
def download_file():
   file_format = request.json.get("file_format") # csv or xlsx
   result_df = internal_func_that_create_df_from_database()
   if file_format == "xlsx":
      bytes_stream = io.BytesIO()
      writer = pd.ExcelWriter(bytes_stream)
      result_df.to_excel(writer, startrow=0, merge_cells=False, sheet_name="Sheet0", index_label=None, index=False)
      writer.close()
      bytes_stream.seek(0)
      return send_file(bytes_stream, download_name="test.xlsx", mimetype="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", as_attachment=True)
   if file_format == "csv":
      response = make_response(result_df.to_csv())
      response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=test.csv"
      response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/csv"
      return response
```

This function produce the 2 types of files right now with no problem, it's working. I would like to have here those two types of files being send in chunks, can anyone suggest/point me into the right direction?

I have made some research here, found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67673514/write-large-dataframes-to-excel-using-flask-and-pandas) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67181411/using-flask-and-pandas-to-stream-response-data-to-excel) but the users have not found an answer, but reading the comments I could learn that xlsx files can't be streamed, so maybe my xlsx solution can't be done for now. From the CSV side I have seen that there is a [Flask Streaming Content page](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/streaming/) that I could try to use, not sure how to use that with a dataframe yet.